# How to check if the 1st letter in a cell is UPPERCASE

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm trying to find out if the 1st letter in a cell is **UPPERCASE**. I know how to convert case using `PROPER()`, `UPPER()`, and `LOWER()`, but not how to detect case.

The following checks every word in the string and returns `false` for `A1` and `true` for `A2`, but I just want to know if the 1st character in the cell is proper, not every word.

```
=EXACT(PROPER(a1),a1)
```

**string in cell `A1`:**

> hello World

**string in cell `A2`:**

> Hello World

Any ideas on a formula that will return `false` for cell `A1` and `true` for cell `A2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A); IF(EXACT(UPPER(LEFT(A1:A; 1)); 
                                           LEFT(A1:A; 1)); TRUE; FALSE); ))
```

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(EXACT(UPPER(LEFT(A1; 1)); 
                LEFT(A1; 1)); TRUE; FALSE)
```

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1,"^[A-Z]"),"true","false")
```

Note, it does work with English uppercase letters, but not with others.

Answer (score 1):

I keep finding myself back on this page when searching in Google (basically trying to remember there's an "EXACT" function, so figured I'd add the following somewhat simpler formula to the accepted answer, a tweak to the solution @user0 provided:

```
=EXACT(UPPER(LEFT(A1,1)),LEFT(A1,1))
```

Also, if you're trying to simply check if an ENTIRE word is uppercase (this page shows up early on Google results), a modification of this formula also works:

```
=EXACT(UPPER(A1),A1)
```

Great if you're working with data from a user base who thinks that caps lock is the only way to complete online forms :)